# Controlling an embedded JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

A client of our company uses JWPlayer for video content. In order to integrate them into our SaaS platform, we are embedding their content using the code they provided:

```
<iframe src="http://video.CLIENTWEBSITE.com/players/MEDIAID-PLAYERID.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowfullscreen style=”position:absolute;”></iframe>
```

The source link in the embed (edited for obvious reasons) has the JWPlayer code in it where one can access the Javascript API to do things like play, pause, etc. I'm looking for a way to either include a reference to the JWPlayer API so I can directly instantiate a jwplayer object (as demonstrated in the API docs) or else use some cross-origin communication like postMessage to send a command to the embedded page. I searched the API docs and StackOverflow but couldn't find an answer. Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the IFRAME method of embedding JW Platform hosted players will basically limit your options for interacting with that JW Player / API from the parent page to simple "play" and "pause" requests.

These requests can be sent to the iframe using the "postMessage" cross-frame messaging technique, but the following are the only "listeners" currently offered.

```
/** Used to pass play/pause messages parent iframe via postMessage **/
window.addEventListener("message", function(evt) {
  switch (evt.data) {
    case "play":
      jwplayer().play(true);
      break;
    case "pause":
      jwplayer().pause(true);
      break;
  }
});
```

Assuming the assets are being linked to from the JW platform, then a potential better approach for you would be to use the direct JS embed on your parent page rather than the IFRAME embed.

This simple involves changing the extension of the URL used from ".html" to ".js" and using a SCRIPT tag instead of an IFRAME:

```
<script src="http://video.CLIENTWEBSITE.com/players/MEDIAID-PLAYERID.js"></script>
```

This will render the player inline in your page providing full access to the JW Player & API. Depending on the way the player is configured in the JW Dashboard, you may need to wrap it in additional furniture in order to control the sizing.